# Delete Functionality in RichtextBox (Windows Forms with .NET 3.5)

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I am facing a problem to implement the delete functionality. The Key_Down event is not getting raised when I pressed a delete key from Keyboard. If I implement the Key_Press OR Key_Up Event.

Suppose I have selected some Text from RichTextBox and pressed the DEL, then the text get removed first and then it reaches to the Event code(Key_Press OR Key_Up Event).

Can anybody help me to resolved this?

Comment: Not sure I am following your question, your question sounds like delete is not working, but here you say delete did delete the text?

Comment: No repro at all.  Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to check for the delete key you could try the KeyPreview event. That should fire before the KeyPress or KeyDown events.